# How to run another .EXE from my application setup ( VS 2010 )

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have a wpf application and I made a setup, and during installation  i need to create database, and edit Connectionstring (app.config). So I made  `CustomAction` add `Installer.cs` and `override Install method` and it done.

Now i need to install `SqlServer Express` from my setup, ie before creating database I should check whether the machine have installed sqlserver if not it should install form my application setup.

As far i know using `process.start()` i can run exe, but problem i am facing where i should keep sql.exe and how to get path

provide any usefull link much appreciated

ScreenShot:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [dotNetInstaller](http://dblock.github.io/dotnetinstaller/) or similar bootstrapper. This solution create only one installer that install other pre-requisites and then execute your Visual Studio setup.

Comment: thanks for replying fast, let me see i never heard, also want to knw is this free to use ?

Comment: Yes, dotNetInstaller is under MIT license.

Comment: @emiguee: Thanks, am installing it, hope soon i solvd it

Comment: check this pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294189/error-while-making-setup-using-dotnetinstaller-installer-exe