# Error while making setup using dotnetInstaller (installer.exe)

Tags: .net, installation, dotnetinstaller

I have a setup of my project names a `Final__.msi` . Before installing project setup i want to install `Sqlserver R2 Express`. So i use dotnetinstaller to created exe . I have put all my pre-requites file under folder names supportedFiles

Here my **Folder structure**:

[image]

---

Now i added `Exe component` for installing sql server.
Whether i am doing it wrong by setting  `executable` as #APPPATH\SUppotedFIels\sql.exe

[image]

Now while creating EXE i got this error

[image]

This is my **Configuration.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configurations lcid_type="UserExe" show_language_selector="False" language_selector_title="" language_selector_ok="OK" language_selector_cancel="Cancel" configuration_no_match_message="" ui_level="full" fileversion="" productversion="" log_enabled="True" log_file="#TEMPPATH\dotNetInstallerLog.txt">
  <schema version="2.2.824.0" generator="dotNetInstaller InstallerEditor" />
  <configuration dialog_caption="SECS Installer" dialog_message="In order to install SECS you must first install these components:" dialog_message_uninstall="" dialog_bitmap="#APPPATH\banner.bmp" skip_caption="Skip" install_caption="Install" uninstall_caption="Uninstall" cancel_caption="Close" status_installed=" (Installed)" status_notinstalled="" failed_exec_command_continue="Failed to install %s. Continue with other components?" installation_completed="SECS installed successfully!" uninstallation_completed="SECS uninstalled successfully!" installation_none="SECS is already installed!" uninstallation_none="SECS is not installed!" installing_component_wait="Installing %s. Wait, this operation could take some time ..." uninstalling_component_wait="Uninstalling %s. Wait, this operation could take some time ..." reboot_required="To continue the installation you must restart your computer. Restart now?" must_reboot_required="False" dialog_otherinfo_caption="" dialog_otherinfo_link="" complete_command="" complete_command_silent="" complete_command_basic="" wait_for_complete_command="True" prompt_for_optional_components="False" auto_close_if_installed="True" auto_close_on_error="False" reload_on_error="True" dialog_show_installed="True" dialog_show_uninstalled="True" dialog_show_required="True" cab_dialog_message="%s" cab_cancelled_message="" cab_dialog_caption="" cab_path="#TEMPPATH\#GUID" cab_path_autodelete="True" dialog_default_button="cancel" dialog_position="" dialog_components_list_position="" dialog_message_position="" dialog_bitmap_position="" dialog_otherinfo_link_position="" dialog_osinfo_position="" dialog_install_button_position="" dialog_cancel_button_position="" dialog_skip_button_position="" auto_start="False" auto_continue_on_reboot="False" reboot_cmd="" show_progress_dialog="True" show_cab_dialog="True" disable_wow64_fs_redirection="False" administrator_required="True" administrator_required_message="SECS installation requires administration rights." type="install" lcid_filter="" language_id="" language="" os_filter="" os_filter_min="" os_filter_max="" processor_architecture_filter="" supports_install="True" supports_uninstall="True">
    <component executable="#CABPATH\SQLEXPWT_X86_ENU.exe" executable_silent="" executable_basic="" install_directory="" responsefile_source="" responsefile_target="" responsefile_format="none" uninstall_executable="" uninstall_executable_silent="" uninstall_executable_basic="" uninstall_responsefile_source="" uninstall_responsefile_target="" returncodes_success="" returncodes_reboot="3010" exeparameters="" exeparameters_basic="" exeparameters_silent="" uninstall_exeparameters="" uninstall_exeparameters_basic="" uninstall_exeparameters_silent="" disable_wow64_fs_redirection="False" id="SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU" display_name="SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU" uninstall_display_name="" os_filter="" os_filter_min="" os_filter_max="" os_filter_lcid="" type="exe" installcompletemessage="" uninstallcompletemessage="" mustreboot="False" reboot_required="" must_reboot_required="True" failed_exec_command_continue="" allow_continue_on_error="True" default_continue_on_error="False" required_install="True" required_uninstall="True" selected_install="True" selected_uninstall="True" note="" processor_architecture_filter="" status_installed="" status_notinstalled="" supports_install="True" supports_uninstall="False" show_progress_dialog="True" show_cab_dialog="True">
      <embedfile sourcefilepath="#APPPATH\SupportedFiles\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe" targetfilepath="SupportedFiles\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe" />
    </component>
    <component package="#CABPATH\FinalSecs.msi" cmdparameters="" cmdparameters_silent="/qn" cmdparameters_basic="/qb-" uninstall_package="" uninstall_cmdparameters="/qb-" uninstall_cmdparameters_silent="/qn" uninstall_cmdparameters_basic="/qb-" disable_wow64_fs_redirection="False" id="FinalSecs" display_name="FinalSecs" uninstall_display_name="" os_filter="" os_filter_min="" os_filter_max="" os_filter_lcid="" type="msi" installcompletemessage="" uninstallcompletemessage="" mustreboot="False" reboot_required="" must_reboot_required="False" failed_exec_command_continue="" allow_continue_on_error="True" default_continue_on_error="False" required_install="True" required_uninstall="True" selected_install="True" selected_uninstall="True" note="" processor_architecture_filter="" status_installed="" status_notinstalled="" supports_install="True" supports_uninstall="True" show_progress_dialog="True" show_cab_dialog="True">
      <embedfile sourcefilepath="#APPPATH\SupportedFiles\Final___.msi" targetfilepath="SupportedFiles\Final___.msi" />
    </component>
  </configuration>
</configurations>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add other Cab file for `SQLEXPWT_X86_ENU.exe` as `Final___.msi`.

Then, change `Install\Executable` parameter from value:

```
#APPPATH\SUppotedFIels\sql.exe
```

to value:

```
#CABPATH\SQLEXPWT_X86_ENU.exe
```

If you open your dotNetInstaller xml configuration file, you should have something like this:

```
  ...
  <configuration ...>
    ...
    <component package="#CABPATH\Final___.msi" ... />
    <component package="#CABPATH\SQLEXPWT_X86_ENU.exe" ... />
    <embedfile sourcefilepath="yourResourcePath\Final___.msi" targetfilepath="" />
    <embedfile sourcefilepath="yourResourcePath\SupportedFiles\SQLEXPWT_X86_ENU.exe" targetfilepath="" />
  </configuration>
```

Detailed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configurations lcid_type="UserExe" show_language_selector="False" language_selector_title="" language_selector_ok="OK" language_selector_cancel="Cancel" configuration_no_match_message="" ui_level="full" fileversion="" productversion="" log_enabled="True" log_file="#TEMPPATH\dotNetInstallerLog.txt">
  <schema version="2.2.824.0" generator="dotNetInstaller InstallerEditor" />
  <configuration dialog_caption="SECS Installer" dialog_message="In order to install SECS you must first install these components:" dialog_message_uninstall="" dialog_bitmap="#APPPATH\banner.bmp" skip_caption="Skip" install_caption="Install" uninstall_caption="Uninstall" cancel_caption="Close" status_installed=" (Installed)" status_notinstalled="" failed_exec_command_continue="Failed to install %s. Continue with other components?" installation_completed="SECS installed successfully!" uninstallation_completed="SECS uninstalled successfully!" installation_none="SECS is already installed!" uninstallation_none="SECS is not installed!" installing_component_wait="Installing %s. Wait, this operation could take some time ..." uninstalling_component_wait="Uninstalling %s. Wait, this operation could take some time ..." reboot_required="To continue the installation you must restart your computer. Restart now?" must_reboot_required="False" dialog_otherinfo_caption="" dialog_otherinfo_link="" complete_command="" complete_command_silent="" complete_command_basic="" wait_for_complete_command="True" prompt_for_optional_components="False" auto_close_if_installed="True" auto_close_on_error="False" reload_on_error="True" dialog_show_installed="True" dialog_show_uninstalled="True" dialog_show_required="True" cab_dialog_message="%s" cab_cancelled_message="" cab_dialog_caption="" cab_path="#TEMPPATH\#GUID" cab_path_autodelete="True" dialog_default_button="cancel" dialog_position="" dialog_components_list_position="" dialog_message_position="" dialog_bitmap_position="" dialog_otherinfo_link_position="" dialog_osinfo_position="" dialog_install_button_position="" dialog_cancel_button_position="" dialog_skip_button_position="" auto_start="False" auto_continue_on_reboot="False" reboot_cmd="" show_progress_dialog="True" show_cab_dialog="True" disable_wow64_fs_redirection="False" administrator_required="True" administrator_required_message="SECS installation requires administration rights." type="install" lcid_filter="" language_id="" language="" os_filter="" os_filter_min="" os_filter_max="" processor_architecture_filter="" supports_install="True" supports_uninstall="True">
    <component executable="#CABPATH\SupportedFiles\SQLEXPWT_X86_ENU.exe" executable_silent="" executable_basic="" install_directory="" responsefile_source="" responsefile_target="" responsefile_format="none" uninstall_executable="" uninstall_executable_silent="" uninstall_executable_basic="" uninstall_responsefile_source="" uninstall_responsefile_target="" returncodes_success="" returncodes_reboot="3010" exeparameters="" exeparameters_basic="" exeparameters_silent="" uninstall_exeparameters="" uninstall_exeparameters_basic="" uninstall_exeparameters_silent="" disable_wow64_fs_redirection="False" id="SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU" display_name="SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU" uninstall_display_name="" os_filter="" os_filter_min="" os_filter_max="" os_filter_lcid="" type="exe" installcompletemessage="" uninstallcompletemessage="" mustreboot="False" reboot_required="" must_reboot_required="True" failed_exec_command_continue="" allow_continue_on_error="True" default_continue_on_error="False" required_install="True" required_uninstall="True" selected_install="True" selected_uninstall="True" note="" processor_architecture_filter="" status_installed="" status_notinstalled="" supports_install="True" supports_uninstall="False" show_progress_dialog="True" show_cab_dialog="True">
      <embedfile sourcefilepath="SupportedFiles\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe" targetfilepath="SupportedFiles\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe" />
    </component>
    <component package="#CABPATH\Final___.msi" cmdparameters="" cmdparameters_silent="/qn" cmdparameters_basic="/qb-" uninstall_package="" uninstall_cmdparameters="/qb-" uninstall_cmdparameters_silent="/qn" uninstall_cmdparameters_basic="/qb-" disable_wow64_fs_redirection="False" id="FinalSecs" display_name="FinalSecs" uninstall_display_name="" os_filter="" os_filter_min="" os_filter_max="" os_filter_lcid="" type="msi" installcompletemessage="" uninstallcompletemessage="" mustreboot="False" reboot_required="" must_reboot_required="False" failed_exec_command_continue="" allow_continue_on_error="True" default_continue_on_error="False" required_install="True" required_uninstall="True" selected_install="True" selected_uninstall="True" note="" processor_architecture_filter="" status_installed="" status_notinstalled="" supports_install="True" supports_uninstall="True" show_progress_dialog="True" show_cab_dialog="True">
      <embedfile sourcefilepath="SupportedFiles\Final___.msi" targetfilepath="Final___.msi" />
    </component>
  </configuration>
</configurations>
```

Comment: thsnk for reply, then what be the  `resourcepath`  of embededfile is it `#APPPATH\SupportedFiles\FinalSecs.msi`

Comment: Also under the `install` –> `self-extracting CAB` – > `cab_path`  `#TEMPPATH\#GUID`, what to be set here ?

Comment: I have set post my configuration.xml, pls have a look